# Using sed, I need to replace all ",\n" with ",\.\n" including the last line

Tags: sed

I have several thousand large text files that I need to clean up.  I need any line that ends with a comma to end with a comma followed by a period (,.).

I found the following, which works for every line except the last line.  It must be close to what I need but I can't figure out how to make it work on the last line as well.

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print  | xargs sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/,\n/,\.\n/g'
```

My data looks something like this:

```
0,0,0,193,17,.,.,
0,0,0,174,19,.,.,
0,0,0,124,14,.,.,
```

I need it to look like this:

```
0,0,0,193,17,.,.,.
0,0,0,174,19,.,.,.
0,0,0,124,14,.,.,.
```

Comment: @larsmans: Your answer was correct except that the backslash and `g` were unnecessary.

Comment: @Dennis: undeleted. I was confused by the OP's branching to a label and the `N` command, thought I missed something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/,$/,./'
```

(`$` means end of line.)

Comment: Thanks!  That saved me a lot of time.